# Connect to icCube server through Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, iccube

I want to fetch data from icCube olap server with Pentaho (5.2.0.0), to create a report. I created a new Data Source with the Data Source Wizard:

[image]

And when clicking on 'Next' button to get the Schemas I got the following error:

[image]

In the icCube logs I have nothing (so it's not even connecting), in the Pentaho log file the following:

```
2015-02-04 16:30:29,908 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.AbstractGwtRpcProxyServlet] com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public java.util.List org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.MultitableDatasourceService.retrieveSchemas(org.pentaho.database.model.IDatabaseConnection) throws org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.DatasourceServiceException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2015-02-04 16:30:29,915 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.AbstractGwtRpcProxyServlet] com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public java.util.List org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.MultitableDatasourceService.getDatabaseTables(org.pentaho.database.model.IDatabaseConnection,java.lang.String) throws org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.DatasourceServiceException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

The connection settings are correct. The connection works from the Data Integration Tool:

[image]

**Update:**

With Pentaho 4.8 I have the following error:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public java.util.List org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.MultitableDatasourceService.retrieveSchemas(org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.IConnection) throws org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.DatasourceServiceException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:378)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:581)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:544)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.servlet.GwtRpcPluginProxyServlet.processCall(GwtRpcPluginProxyServlet.java:131)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoWebContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoWebContextFilter.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.PentahoRequestContextFilter.doFilter(PentahoRequestContextFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.SecurityStartupFilter.doFilter(SecurityStartupFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterAuthenticationFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.security.HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionReuseDetectionFilter.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SystemStatusFilter.doFilter(SystemStatusFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.getTables(XmlaOlap4jDatabaseMetaData.java:733)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getTableMap(Database.java:3906)
    at org.pentaho.platform.dataaccess.datasource.wizard.service.impl.MultitableDatasourceService.retrieveSchemas(MultitableDatasourceService.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: Buddy; I don't find anything. But Can you check with changing port number in Database Connection? Try with another port instead of 8282.

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact cause of this error is, but even if you could create a datasource this way, it would probably not work at runtime. The pentaho data access dialog lets you add JDBC connections, mondrian models and MQL (metadata) models. Although technically an OLAP4J driver is JDBC driver, most if not all tools will expect to be executing SQL against it, which it won't support. Just curious - what is it exactly you want to do with this icCube connection inside pentaho?